# MinGW's ar.exe "could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: no more archived files" error upon building in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

So I am trying to build [Odamex](https://odamex.net) in Codeblocks and running into a problem that I have not found any solution to. I am erroring out in the first build sequence with this specific error:

```
ar.exe: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: no more archived files
```

full readout:

```
cmd /c if exist ..\..\lib\libtextscreen.a del ..\..\lib\libtextscreen.a
ar.exe -r -s ..\..\lib\libtextscreen.a ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_button.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_checkbox.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_desktop.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_dropdown.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_fileselect.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_gui.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_inputbox.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_io.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_label.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_radiobutton.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_scrollpane.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_sdl.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_separator.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_spinctrl.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_strut.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_table.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_utf8.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_widget.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_window.o ..\..\obj\libtextscreen\gcc\release\txt_window_action.o
ar.exe: creating ..\..\lib\libtextscreen.a
ar.exe: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: no more archived files
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

From googling it seems it may be related to folder permissions, but I have full permissions on all folders.

Has anyone else ran into this error when building a project on Codeblocks?? Cant find any other threads.  Any hints would be great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem trying to build a static lib via Eclipse and I am confused too.

using toolchain "MinGW GCC" with CDT internal builder:

```
19:37:16 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project myLibS ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o q1.o "..\\q1.c" 
ar -r libmyLibS.a q1.o 
ar: creating libmyLibS.a
ar: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: no more archived files

19:37:17 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 906ms)
```

So far I have only found a workaraoound
using toolchain "cygwin GCC" with CDT internal builder:

```
19:14:37 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project myLibS ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o q1.o "..\\q1.c" 
ar -r libmyLibS.a q1.o 
/usr/bin/ar: creating libmyLibS.a

19:14:37 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 937ms)
```

I hope somebody has a solution to that MinGW problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but only when I added or modified Environment settings under the C/C++ Build project options.

I have found that, if I select (underneath the environment variables) "Append variables to native environment" the error goes away.